# Прервать цикл for...in при совпадении

Tags: javascript

Как прервать цикл при нахождении совпадения? Функция перекликивает табы на странице. Должна остановиться на табе, локатор которого я передал в nameOfTab.

```
goOnTab: function(nameOfTab){
      for (let nameOfTab in locators.tabs){
        if (nameOfTab === locators.tabs)
        break;
        this.click(locators.tabs[nameOfTab])
      }
```

Структура хранения локаторов:

```
const locators = {
  tabs: {
      home: 'Товары для дома',
      girl: 'Женская одежда и аксессуары',
      bag: 'Чемоданы и сумки',
      sport: 'Хобби, спорт, путешествия',
      children: 'Детские товары',
  }}
```

Данный вариант заканчивает на одну итерацию раньше, чем нужно:

```
function(last) {
    for (let nameOfTab in locators.tabs) {
        if (nameOfTab === last) {
            break;
        } 
        this.click(locators.tabs[nameOfTab])
    }
}
```

Comment: вы не забыли, что инструкция break прерывает не только цикл, но и текущую итерацию?

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо большое. Решил вопрос дополнительной строчкой вне цикла

Comment: @moli подумайте ещё раз, есть решение без дублирования строк

Comment: Что-то не ясно. Если передал sport - он и остановится на нём, если передал girl - то на нём.

Comment: метод goOnTab - кривой, при этом функция последняя нормальная и делает то, что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Переменная `nameOfTab` объявленная в цикле перекрывает одноимённый аргумент функции.
2. Значение в `nameOfTab` строка гарантированно никогда не равна объекту `locators.tabs`.